# Interpreting a VisualVM backtrace

Tags: clojure, profiling, visualvm

I'm doing CPU profiling on my Mandelbrot Set explorer. For some reason, `java.lang.PersistentHashMap$BitmapIndexedNode.find` is using a fairly large percentage of the total CPU time. When I take a snapshot of the profiling results, and get a backtrace of the method, I get this:

[image: VisualVM Backtrace Image]

I see lots of references to `BigDecimal` operations. It seems as though `BigDecimal` operators at some point require calling `find` on a `PersistentHashMap`.

Is my interpretation of the backtrace correct? Are calls to `find` a result of `BigDecimal` operations, meaning there's nothing I can do about it? That seems like an odd thing for them to require. I'm having a hard time digging deeper than `clojure.lang.Numbers$BigDecimalOps` though to verify this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. Addition, multiplication, negation, division and other `BigDecimal` operations end up doing hash maps look ups. Those are a part of de-referencing the `*math-context*` Var. It happens every time an arithmetic operation on two `BigDecimal` objects is performed in Clojure. There is nothing that can be done about it short of switching to other numerical types, like `double`.

The `clojure.core/*math-context*` dynamic Var does not have a docstring. As far as I can tell, it is intended to hold a [java.math.MathContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) object. MathContext objects can be used to specify precision and [rounding mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) for BigDecimal operations. If `*math-context*` is bound, its value is passed to BigDecimal methods in the Java runtime as in [BigDecimal.add(BigDecimal augend, MathContext mc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-java.math.MathContext-). When `*math-context*` is not bound, BigDecimal methods are called [without passing a context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add-java.math.BigDecimal-).

The relevant part of the stack trace from the question is:

```
...
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap.entryAt(Object)
clojure.lang.Var.getThreadBinding()
clojure.lang.Var.deref()
clojure.lang.Numbers$BigDecimalOps.add/multiply/..
...
```

Some pointers to Clojure source code:

- `*math-context*` Var [defined](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L200)
- `*math-context*` de-referenced when BigDecimal [addition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java#L928) is performed. Same thing happens for other operations too
- Dereferencing a Var requires a call to [getThreadBinding](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L195)
- A hash map [is looked up](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java#L355) inside `getThreadBinding`